# In a book manuscript, what are the spacing guidelines?

Tags: formatting, book

1. What is the spacing distance between the chapter title and the first paragraph?
2. If I am using double spacing between sentences, is it the same for between a title and a paragraph?

Comment: Edited to clarify what you were asking in the title and separate your two questions. If I misread feel free to edit however!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this source](https://www.scribophile.com/academy/how-to-format-a-novel-manuscript#:%7E:text=Lines%20should%20be%20double%20spaced,by%20hitting%20the%20tab%20key.) about how to format a novel manuscript:

### Margin spacing:

- Document margins should be **3 cm** on all sides.

### Line and paragraph spacing:

- Lines should be **double-spaced** with **no extra space between paragraphs.**
- Font should be **twelve-point** in either Times New Roman, Courier or Arial, depending on the specific preferred style(s) of the publishing house you're submitting to.

### Chapter formatting:

- **Begin chapters on new pages** by placing a page break before the chapter heading.
- **Center chapter titles** and **skip a few spaces before the chapter text.**

There are likely other guidelines that differ between publishing houses, but these would be good general rules to follow to make the manuscript look professional.

[This Writing SE question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/29306/what-is-the-line-spacing-in-novels) also contains some helpful advice if you'd like to take a look. (It's not strictly a duplicate of your question, but it asks a similar question and has a helpful answer.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.